# I use border-radius for round my image element but it's not completely rounded

Tags: html, css

sorry for my English...

look at below code

```
 img {
    max-width: 100%;
 }
 #avatar-img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
 }
```

This is output. It is not completely rounded

[image]

Now my question is how to round this image? what's wrong with this code?

Comment: it seems *completely* rounded to me. Defined *completely rounded*

Comment: A _square_ image with a border-radius >= 50% would give you an actual _circle_. A non-square image does not …

Comment: You have to use fixed width and height. Also need width = height. Then you can get rounded image.

Comment: I set width and height the same but the image is not rounded yet. width and height = 50%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use for `border-radius` a percentage value, but the height and the widht of your image are not the same. It is logical that a percentage of two values which are not the same give you different results, therefore it isn't round.

If you want  to make it round use an image where width and height are the same.
You can set `width` and `height` to the same value

Comment: I set width and height = 50% but it's still the same.

Comment: Then you just make it smaller. You have to set them to a fixed pixel value or use javascript to set the ``width`` to the ``height``

Comment: I set width and height with px and my problem solved. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the same height, width and 50% border-radius to image and it will perfectly round your image. for example see below example.

```css
img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
#avatar-img {
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar-img">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/240/240/any" />
</div>
```

In this example my image have 240 `width` and `height` so you just set your image width and height.
`width:240px;`
`height:240px;`
and change the image src and see the result.